# How to change GridView column header text in c# web form?

Tags: c#, database, gridview

I want to change GridView column header text, because its automatically putting from MSSQL database. I tried this code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "AGENT ID";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "NAME";

    }
```

Now, this code only changing the the first Column Header text. I tried this too

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "AGENT ID";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "NAME";

    }
```

and the data table is not showing after applying these changes.

Where i am wrong? Please try to provide full code.

Comment: More information would help. For example, are you trying to change all the column headers or just a subset of the data? Are you creating the GridView control in the aspx page or dynamically in the .cs page? The answer to those questions will help lead to a better response for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that :

1 - change you select query like this :

```
 Select name as [YourNewName]
```

2 - Set the header text in a C# method :

```
 DataGridViewName.Columns[1].HeaderText = "YourNewName";
```

Answer (score 0):

your provided code is execute totally fine. the error might be some other part. please provide the full code for better understanding.

Though you can access Header row by calling `GridView1.HeaderRow`properties.

As you calling `RowDataBound` Events, which is fired after every row bound. access the `DataBound` Events in this case which is only fire once after the entire Gridview Bound.

here is the full code.

aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "AGENT ID";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "NAME";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks Dipak, Just followed your guide and it worked like a charm. Can you tell me what should i do if i want to display more than 1 GridView (Gridview1 and GridView2) in the same page? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Jason there is nothing Wrong with Your approach you just need to **`Assign GridView1_RowDataBound to your Gridview`** Like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
```

and you `Event` will be called and it will work fine for you

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "AGENT ID";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "NAME";
        }
```